# Leading zero in XLS column is getting removed

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xls

We are using following code to generate xml/csv report file.

Code:

```
        Object attachmentXml = attachmentXML;
        ReportsXml reporstXml = XmlUtils.Deserialize<ReportsXml>((string)attachmentXML);
        ReportFormatter.Report.ReportFormatter formatter = new ReportFormatter.Report.ReportFormatter();
        MimeTypeEnum mimeType = EnumHelper.GetValueFromDescription<MimeTypeEnum>(reporstXml.Reports[0].ReportType);
        string fileExtension = mimeType == MimeTypeEnum.XLS ? ".xls" : ".csv";
        byte[] report = formatter.FormatReport(reporstXml, mimeType);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(report);
        FileStream file = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/TempUploadFiles/" + fileName + fileExtension), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        stream.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        stream.Close();
```

Our report file contains zip code column and when zip code has leading zero, it is getting removed while generating a file.

I tried few things like adding `'`, `=`,`\t`,`" "`, `&nbsp;` before actual value but no success. Actually adding `'` before value worked but `'` was there in xml file with original data which I don't want.

Is there anything I can try?

Comment: This code don't show the part required for answer. You should change the type of your ZIP code from number to string. Leading zeros in numbers will get cut of but not in strings.

Comment: Open file with notepad and see if leading zeroes are in the file.  It just may be the viewer you are using that is removing the zeroes.

Comment: Hi Jdweng, using notepad as viewer causing data corruption.

Comment: Hi @Emad, Zip code is a part of XML which is passed as string to ReportFormatter. We are converting XML data to bytes while formatting it so not getting how deal with type of column.

Comment: If you have no control over the XML you have no choice but to deserialize xml and change the type of zip code and re-serialize it. Or alternatively find a way to specify column type of excel document to text. Which I don't know a way

Comment: Show me a sample of zip code in the xml (with tags) I have an idea

Comment: This is just one of those infuriating things about Excel: it tries to be clever and sometimes gets it wrong. If a field is numeric, it thinks that leading zeroes aren't significant, and the only ways around it are (a) to change the type of the column or cell, or (b) the leading-apostrophe hack.

Comment: @MichaelKay, as I mentioned in above comment, we are convertin XML to bytes using ReportFormmater so I am not getting how to change the type of a column and personally feels adding leading-apostrophe is not  good solution cause every ZipCode is displayed with apostrophe eg.  '01803

Comment: @Emad, Here is XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Reports xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<Report><ReportType>xls</ReportType><Name>XYZ</Name>
<Advertiser>TCS</Advertiser><FromDate>12/24/2019</FromDate><ToDate>01/07/2020</ToDate><ColumnCount>7</ColumnCount>
<Row><Cell><Name>Zip code</Name><Value>01803</Value></Cell></Row></Report></Reports>

Comment: I'm afraid my plan can't work on this XML. See two more thing. First see if `ReportFormatter` accepts `XSD` or only XML. My second things is that you can add a post processing on the excel file and and fix the number of digits on zip code.

Comment: For the record, I'm still on my initial proposal of deserializing the XML and reserialize it again.